# SQLAlchemy: limit in the same string as where

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

We're trying to enable a SQL query front-end to our Web application, which is WSGI and uses Python, with SQLAlchemy (core, not ORM) to query a PostgreSQL database.  We have several data layer functions set up to assist in query construction, and we are now trying to set something up that allows this type of query:

```
select id from <table_name> where ... limit ...
```

In the front end, we have a text box which lets the user type in the where clause and the limit clause, so that the data can be queried flexibly and dynamically from the front end, that is, we want to enable *ad hoc* querying.  So, the only thing that we now firsthand is:

```
select id from <table_name>
```

And the user will type in, for example:

```
where date > <some_date>
where location is not null limit 10 order by location desc
```

using the **same** back end function.  The select, column and table should be managed by the data layer (i.e. it knows what they are, and the user should not need to know that).  However, I'm not aware of any way to get SQLAlchemy to automatically parse both the `where` clause and the `limit` clause automatically.  What we have right now is a function which can return the table name and the name of the id column, and then use that to create a text query, which is passed to SQLAlchemy, as the input to a `text()` call.

Is there any way I can do this with SQLAlchemy, or some other library?  Or is there a better pattern of which I should be aware, which does not involve parsing the SQL while still allowing this functionality from the front-end?

Thanks a lot!  All suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why are you "parsing" anything?  SQLAlchemy will _generate_ SQL for you, piecemeal.  i don't understand how you're trying to use it here.  can you post some code?

Comment: @Eevee: I understand how SQLAlchemy works, but in this case, I am not creating the statements programatically. Please see edits above.

Comment: Maybe something like http://www.wiggy.net/articles/sqlalchemy-in-reverse would help?

Comment: @Audrius Kazukauskas: Definitely something like what we want, but I would prefer to have a more established library.  In any case, write this comment as an answer and I'll definitely upvote / accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow, but the general SQL-Alchemy usage is like:

```
 results = db.session.query(User).filter(User.name == "Bob").order_by(User.age.desc()).limit(10)
```

That will query the User table to return the top ten oldest members named "Bob"

Comment: Correct.  I did not explain the purpose of my question properly.  The functionality we want to achieve are _ad hoc_ queries, of which, by definition, we don't know the structure beforehand.  Thanks!

Comment: Without a whole lot of parsing, I don't see an easy way of doing it with the SQlAlchemy ORM. Amy reason not to use web input boxes? THen you could certainly build up the query with the ORM.

Comment: Also, if this is a publicly available site, this sort of thing is pretty dangerous.

Comment: It's not publicly available.  It's an internal app with authentication.  Thanks for the warning, though.